# g_resources is not defined in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-js

I am writing a cocos2d code and want to run my first scene defined in res folder and have to perform ontouch event on it.I have written a code but it is giving an error that "g_resources not defined"

Below is the code of my "main.js" file in which the error occured:

```
"use strict";
var cocos2dApp = cc.Application.extend({
    config : document.ccConfig,
    ctor : function(scene) {
        this._super();
        this.startScene = scene;
        cc.COCOS2D_DEBUG = this.config['COCOS2D_DEBUG'];
        cc.setup(this.config['tag']);
        cc.AppController.shareAppController().didFinishLaunchingWithOptions();
    },
    applicationDidFinishLaunching : function() {
        var that = this;
        // initialize director
        var director = cc.Director.getInstance();
        var resourceSize = cc.size(1024, 768);
        var designSize = cc.size(1024, 768);
        var policy = new cc.ResolutionPolicy(cc.ContainerStrategy.PROPORTION_TO_FRAME, cc.ContentStrategy.NO_BORDER);
          cc.EGLView.getInstance().setDesignResolutionSize(designSize.width,designSize.height,policy);

        cc.EGLView.getInstance().resizeWithBrowserSize(true);

//        director.setContentScaleFactor(2,2)
        // enable High Resource Mode(2x, such as iphone4) and maintains low
        // resource on other devices.
        // director->enableRetinaDisplay(true);

//        cc.setScaleX(0.5)
//        cc.setScaleY(0.5)

//        this.scale(0.5,0.5)

        // turn on display FPS
        director.setDisplayStats(this.config['showFPS']);

        // set FPS. the default value is 1.0/60 if you don't call this
        director.setAnimationInterval(1.0 / this.config['frameRate']);

        // create a scene. it's an autorelease object

        // load resources and run
        cc.LoaderScene.preload(g_resources, function() {
            var startSceneInstance = new that.startScene();
            director.replaceScene(startSceneInstance);
        });

        return true;
    }
});

var myApp = new cocos2dApp(helloworldScene);
```

i had stored all my images in "resource.js" and variable name is same as g_resources.
I dont know why it is giving this error.Can anybody help me wwith the soloution

Comment: g_resources is not defined means you need to define it. I don't know much about javascript but it seems like you need to add a var g_resources line.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Cocos2D-JS v3.0 (rc3)? If I'm not wildly mistake, that code looks like
 it's from v2.3. If you are starting out, I highly reccomend you start by learning 3.0.

Now, if you really wish to procceed with using v2.3, you'll most likely need to go into your `cocos2d.js` configs file and look at `appFiles` and make sure that `"src/resource.js"` (or whatever the path it is) is placed there *before* any `.js` file that contains code that requires use of `g_resources`.

If you were using Cocos2D-JS v3.0 and your code was ok but you got that error, here's what you could do: check your `project.json` config file, in it look at `"jsList"` and make sure that `"src/resource.js"` (or whatever the path it is) is placed there *before* any `.js` file that contains code that requires use of `g_resources`.

I may be mistaken, but that strict precedence would probably not be needed if you hadn't put the browser in strict mode with `"use strict";` at the beggining (that said, I quite prefer that little cons in contrast of all the pros that using strict mode gives).

If the problem is that you are using JSHint and you get that error in your editor, make sure to place a `/*global g_resource*/` at the beggining of the file where you get the error.

Another work around is, also at the beginning of the file write `var g_resource = g_resource || []`.